# Problems installing sFrame package

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, sframe

In this moment I have problems installing this package from github
https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame
I use a windows 10, it is to python version 2.7

I Tried to use

```
pip install https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame
```

It does not work.

Then I tried to use

```
pip install --process-dependency-links
```

git+ssh://git@github.com/nhooey/package.git

```
Invalid requirement: ''git+ssh://git@github.com/turi-code/SFrame.git''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 92, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1617, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1607, in parseString
    loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3376, in parseImpl
    loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3698, in parseImpl
    return self.expr._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1379, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3359, in parseImpl
    loc, resultlist = self.exprs[0]._parse( instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse=False )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1383, in _parseNoCache
    loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 2670, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected W:(abcd...) (at char 0), (line:1, col:1)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "c:\users\enver\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at ""'git+ssh""
```

---

Then I downloaded the package from github and use

```
pip install c:\Python27\Scripts\SFrame-master\cxxtest\python

Processing c:\python27\scripts\sframe-master\cxxtest\python
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    error: error in 'egg_base' option: 'pip-egg-info' does not exist or is not a directory
```

---

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Enver\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-66c2rgaw-build\
```

Any idea please to install this package?

Answer (score 2):

I am using python 3 inside a macOS machine, with *virtualenv*. I downloaded the SFrame .tar.gz package from its [pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SFrame), and then installed it with *pip install SFrame-2.1-py2.7.tar.gz*. This way it worked for me.